# How can I disable mouse-wheel history scrolling in tmux when mouse mode is off?

Tags: tmux

When using touchpad, my palms tend to trigger a slight mouse scroll, so I've disable mouse altogether in tmux using `set -g mouse off`. When I do this, however, mouse-wheel events will scroll history instead of scrolling the window. It only does this inside tmux (if I detach, the behavior goes away). Anyone know how to disable this? I'm using Arch Linux and Gnome Terminal.

Comment: Better if you can provide more details like OS, terminal emulator, etc. Also, I've tried the same on Terminal App on El Capitan and I faced the same issue. However, I could not reproduce the same on iTerm2.

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux and Gnome Terminal.

Comment: The inability to do this makes using tmux with a laptop touchpad useless for me.  Why the default is to scroll the shell history with the mouse in tmux, I just don't understand.  Nor can I disable it so far.  I don't want to go back to screen, but it does at least work, and also doesn't screw up tty settings (try stty intr ^? for instance).